# Execute a PHP code inside jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

That's what I have:

```
<a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>#nav-link">LinkName</a>
```

Here `<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>` I'm getting some link, and I want to add to the end of this link some extra hashtag parameter `#nav-link`.

But the main problem is that PHP is executing on the server side, so, when I click the link, I get only link from the `<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>` (blabla.com). After second click, I have necessary code `blabla.com/#nav-link`.

So, is it possible to get `blabla.com/#nav-link` after first click?

Comment: use anything but the # if you want it to be sent to the server and not just the browser

Comment: You could set a var in jquery and have PHP populate that variable with what you want and then use that var in your code further down the line.

Comment: If you want to change the link after the page loads - why don't you just use jQuery to append the link instead of relying on PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something to the tune of this:

```
<script>
  var data = <?php echo $arItem["LINK"]; ?>

  var yourLink = "blabla.com/"+data;

  //more of your code etc....

  $('#yourDiv_where_you_want_the_link').html(yourLink);

 </script>
```